# What is the best practice between setting a variable public or using getters in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, access

From the [solidity.readthedocs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html), a variable declared as `public` does not need a getter since an automatic accessor function is generated e.g:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract C {
    uint public data;
}
```

The variable data, can also be reached using some getters:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
    contract C {
          uint data;

      function getData() constant returns (uint retData) {
        return data;
      }
}
```

My question is simple: **What is the best practice?**

Comment: Be careful of "best practice" questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing  That said, I think this is a reasonable question and the 2 answers right now bring up good points (though they didn't upvote the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple value types like `uint` and `bytes32`, use the `public` modifier. This is less verbose and often more efficient.

If you need to access more complicated types like structs and arrays, it often makes sense to create your own getter to return the data in a format that makes sense for your use case.

Essentially, use the `public` modifier when you can, but don't try to force it to do anything sophisticated.

Answer (score 4):

Your `public` and `internal` fields can still be modified by your child contract. I can think of situations when this may be a problem:

1. if a data change needs to be followed by some action, like an event.
2. if the data should not be modified by mistake by a child contract.

If you are in this situation, you should make the field `private` and create a getter and a setter with access rights of their own.

Otherwise, just make it `public`. Making it `internal` is not really hiding it because anyone, with minimal effort, has access to the whole data anyway.